# How can I determine the value of $a_1 + \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{2012}\frac{a_{i + 1}^3}{a_i^2 + a_ia_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math

For reals $x \ge 3$, let $f(x)$ denote the function $f(x) = \frac{-x + x\sqrt{4x - 3}}{2}$. Now suppose that $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{2013}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $a_1 > 3, a_{2013} = 2013$, and for $n = 1, 2, \ldots, 2012$, $a_{n + 1} = f(a_n)$.

Given this, how can I determine the value of $$a_1 + \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{2012}\frac{a_{i + 1}^3}{a_i^2 + a_ia_{i + 1} + a_{i + 1}^2}$$

Comment: This smells a lot like a 2- or 3-year-old contest question. Can you say something about where you found it?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think its from IMO

Comment: Please show your own attempt or else the question might be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle A= a_1 +\sum_{i=1}^{2012} \frac{a_{i+1}^3}{a_i^2+a_ia_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2} = a_1 +\sum_{i=1}^{2012} \frac{a_{i+1}^3-a_i^3+a_i^3}{a_i^2+a_ia_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2}$$
$$\displaystyle = a_1 +\sum_{i=1}^{2012} (a_{i+1} -a_i) +\sum_{i=1}^{2012} \frac{a_i^3}{a_i^2+a_ia_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2}$$
The first sum is solved using telescoping series property to get $\displaystyle -a_1+a_{2013}$.

Now we have $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{-x+x\sqrt{4x-3}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle a_{i+1}=f(a_i)$
$$\displaystyle x^2 +xf(x) +f(x)^2 = x^2 +f(x) (x+f(x))= x^2 +f(x) \left (x+ \frac{-x+x\sqrt{4x-3}}{2}\right )$$
$$\displaystyle =x^2+ \frac{-x+x\sqrt{4x-3}}{2} \frac{x+x\sqrt{4x-3}}{2} $$
$$\displaystyle = x^2 + \frac{-4x^2 +4x^3}{4} = x^3$$ $$\displaystyle \Rightarrow a_i^2+a_ia_{i+1}+a_{i+1}^2 = a_i^3 \quad\text{(let } \displaystyle x=a_i\text{)}$$
$$\displaystyle \Rightarrow A= a_1-a_1+a_{2013} +\sum_{i=1}^{2012} 1 = 2013+2012=4025$$

Comment: Yep. That's a contest problem, alright.

Comment: @martycohen Do you know where it's from? I don't think its from IMO, it doesn't seem that it is at that caliber

Comment: Don't know where it's from, but this is the type of problem that is readily solvable using some unexpected insight and almost totally impossible otherwise.

Comment: @martycohen I found it. It's from OMO, Check out #23 on this: http://internetolympiad.org/archive/OMOFall12/OMOFall12Solns.pdf

Comment: Sometimes I am right.

Comment: Thank you for the link and answer